# Why doesn't the QThread object have a finished signal when creating a worker QObject?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, signals, qthread

I know that there are 2 methods of multi-threading using QThreads, One is to subclass QThread and override the run() method, other is to create a QObject class and move it's instance to QThread. the latter is said to be a better practice.

I found out that subclassing QThread does provide a `finished` method which can be used but when creating a separate QObject as a worker thread, QThread will no longer emit the `finished` signal. It seems that the QThrean run method creates an event loop which when is re-implemented, returns the function and emits a `finished` signal. but for in case of a worker class we will need to call a `quit()` method on the QThread object.

Is this correct? Does it not make subclassing QThread more flexible to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the run method is overridden then the logic is implemented there so you can know when it ends, but in the case of moving a QObject to a QThread there is no way to determine when the QObject logic is finished executing.

An alternative is to create a finished signal that you emit when you consider that the QObject logic ends.

Comment: So the `run` method originally has an exec method which creates an event loop and thus never actually "finishes" unless a `quit()` method is called? You suggested creating a custom finished signal. How about calling a `quit()` it finishes the event loop and emits a `finished` signal?

Comment: @Sherafati Forget about emulating the initial logic, one solution is to connect the finished signal to a slot that invokes the quit method of the qthread

Comment: You mean i should create a custom finished signal and emit it whenever i feel like to, then connect it to a `QThread.quit()`?

Comment: Is it basically necessary to manually terminate the QThread (by calling quit)? What if it's event loop is never stopped?